# Android App WIDGET - voice recognizer

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to run an app widget in background with voice recognizer open?

Thank you.
Flinx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App widget is very very dumb itself, and does not execute anything. It's just a data structire to render limited set of views over the homescreen managed by  homescreen. 
You will need background service for this